# PHP: How to display a variable (a) within another variable(b) when variable (b) contains text

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am storing text in my database.
Here is the following text:

```
".$teamName.", is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design ".$sector."
```

After querying the database I assign this text to a variable called `$news`, then echo it.

However the text is outputted to the screen exactly as above without the variables `$teamName*`and `$sector` replaced by there corresponding values.

I assure you that both `$teamName` and `$sector` are defined before I query the database.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be better off using [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php) here.

```
$string = "%s is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design %s.";

$teamName = "My Company";
$sector = "sector";

echo sprintf($string, $teamName, $sector);
// My Company is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design sector.
```

In your database, you store `$string`.  Use `sprintf()` to substitute the variable values.

Comment: Indeed. This is safer and probably faster than `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, I guess: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but did you store the variable names in the database because maybe they were in single quotes and not evaluated?

`$foo = 'bar';echo '$foo'; //$foo`

`$foo = 'bar';echo "$foo"; //bar`

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. If you want `$teamname` to be evaluated, you need to evaluate it before you store it in the database. If you need them to vary, you could do some sort of string replace for all variables.

SQL: `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( 'My team has won ##num_won## games this year.')`

PHP:

```
$string = get_string_from_sql(); // substitute for whatever method you are using to get the string.
$num_won = 16;
$string = str_replace('##num_won##', $num_won, $string);
echo $string; // Will echo My team has won 16 games this year.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing the following string in your database (slightly different to yours):

```
$teamName, is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design $sector.
```

Then, you can do one of two things:

```
$news = eval('return "'.$news.'";');
```

...or...

```
$news = str_replace(array('$teamName','$sector'),array($teamName,$sector),$news);
```

Or better yet, use `sprintf()`, where the string is:

```
%s, is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design %s.
```

...and you get the actual value like this:

```
$news = sprintf($news, $teamName, $sector);
```