# PHP: Most efficient way to display a variable within text when the text could be one of many possibilities

Tags: php, templates, eval, printf, replace

Below is a link to my original question:

[PHP: How to display a variable (a) within another variable(b) when variable (b) contains text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329454/php-how-to-display-a-variable-a-within-another-variableb-when-variable-b/8329599#8329599)

Ok here's more to the problem, all your suggestions work but now I'm looking for the most efficient method to my specific problem.

In my database I have several blocks of text. When a user(described as `$teamName`) logs in to the site, they are randomly assigned one of these blocks of text. Each block of text is different and may have different variables in it.

The problem is I don't have knowledge of which block of text is assigned to the user without actually viewing the database or running a query. So at the moment I have to query the database and select the `$newsID` that corresponds to the block of text that the user has been assigned.

Because I have preset the blocks of text, I know what they contain so I can know do a `switch($newsID)` and depending on the value of the `$newsID` I then run the correct values inserted into the `sprintf()` function.

There is however, many many blocks of text so there will be many instances of `case "":` and `break;`. I wish to have the site working so that if at any stage I change a block of text to something different, then the variables within sprintf() are automatically updated, rather than me manually updating `sprintf()` within the `switch()` `case:`.

Sorry for the long post, hope it makes sense.

EDIT:
I have these **predetermined** blocks of text in my database in my teamNews table:

For `$newsID = 1`:

```
"$teamName is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative hairdryer design
$sector"
```

For `$newsID = 2`:

```
"The government is excited about the potential of ".$teamName.", after they made an annoucement that they have hired $HoM"
```

For `$newsID = 3`:

```
"It is rumored that $teamName are valuing their hairdryer at $salePrice. People are getting excited.
```

When a user(`$teamName`) logs into the game they are randomly assigned one of these blocks of text with `$newsID` of 1,2 or 3.
Lets say the user is assigned the block of text with `$newsID` = 2. So now their username(`$teamName`) is inserted into the database into the same row as their selected text.

Now I want to display the text corresponding to this user so I do the following:

```
$news = news ($currentStage,$teamName);

switch ($ID)
{

    case "1":

    sprintf($teamName,$sector)
    echo $news."<br/><hr/>";    

    break;


    case "2":
    sprintf($teamName,$Hom)
    break;

    case "3":
        sprintf($teamName,$saleprice)
    break;

}



$currentStage--;

}
```

With the function

```
function news($period,$teamName)
{


$news = mysql_query("

    SELECT `content`,`newsID` FROM `teamnews` WHERE `period` = '$period' && `teamName` = '$teamName'

    ") or die($news."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());


    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($news);
    $news = $row['content'];
    $ID = $row ['newsID']; 
    return $news,$ID;

}
```

The problem is that in reality there are about 20 different blocks of text that the user could be assigned to. So I will have many `case:`'s.
Also if I want to change all the text blocks in the database I would have to also manually change all the variables in the `sprintf`'s in each ``case:`

I am wondering is there a better way to do this so that if I change the text in the database then the paramaters passed to `sprintf` will change accordingly.

So if I use

```
$replaces = array(
 'teamName' => 'Bob the team',
 'sector' => 'murdering',
 'anotherSector' => 'giving fluffy bunnies to children'
);
```

is it possible to do this:

```
$replaces = array(
 '$teamName' => '$teamName',
 '$sector' => '$sector',
 '$anotherSector' => '$anothersector'
);
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't make much sense. can you show a (small+short) sample of your text blocks and what you'd expect as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have fixed set of named placeholders, and use either the `str_replace()` or `eval()` (evil) methods of substitution.

So you would (for example) always have a `$teamName` and a `$sector` - and you might only sometimes use `$anotherSector`. And you have these two strings:

```
1 - $teamName, is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative $sector.
2 - The people at $teamName hate working in $sector, they would much rather work in $anotherSector
```

If you were to do:

```
$replaces = array(
  '$teamName' => 'Bob the team',
  '$sector' => 'murdering',
  '$anotherSector' => 'giving fluffy bunnies to children'
);
$news = str_replace(array_keys($replaces),array_values($replaces),$news);
```

You would get

```
1 - Bob the team, is the name of a recently formed company hoping to take over the lucrative murdering.
2 - The people at Bob the team hate working in murdering, they would much rather work in giving fluffy bunnies to children
```

As long as your placeholders have known names, they don't all have to be present in the string - only the relevant ones will be replaced.

Comment: He could also use a simple template engine like mustache: http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: Ok thanks please see my edit above, so do I have to type out the contents of the variable $teamName to be 'Bob the team' or can I not just call the variable $teamName;

Comment: Oh, I think I get it... You can do what you ask, but remove the single quotes from around the array values

Comment: @user1064028 Where are you getting `$sector`, `$HoM` and `$salePrice` from? Regardless of that, your array would just look like `$replaces = array(
  '$teamName' => $teamName,
  '$sector' => $sector,
  '$HoM' => $HoM,
  '$salePrice' => $salePrice
);`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple template language, and store templates in your database.
You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for this.

```
function replaceTemplateVars($str, $data) {
    // change the key format to correspond to the template replacement format
    $replacepairs = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $replacepairs["{{{$key}}}"] = $value;
    }
    // do the replacement in bulk
    return strtr($str, $replacepairs);
}

// store your teamNews table text in this format
// double curly braces is easier to spot and less ambiguous to parse than `$name`.
$exampletemplate = '{{teamName}} is {{sector}} the {{otherteam}}!!'

// get $values out of your database for the user
$values = array(
    'teamName' => 'Bob the team',
    'sector' => 'murdering',
    'otherteam' => 'fluffy bunnies'
);

echo replaceTemplateVars($exampletemplate, $values);
// this will echo "Bob the team is murdering the fluffy bunnies!!"
```

If you have needs more ambitious than this, such as looping or filters, you should find a third-party php template language and use it.

Answer (score 0):

What about function `eval`?
http://php.net/eval